# Can I mix Ruby, Sinatra, and Grunt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, gruntjs, sinatra

This is probably more of a Ruby question cause I think it would apply to Rails as well, but can I mix Ruby and GruntJS? I want to use Grunt to compile Sass and Coffeescript. I know there are ruby gems - in fact the Grunt Sass plugin even uses the Ruby gem - but I have been using Grunt for other projects for a long time and I feel really comfortable with it.

Here is a basic outline of my file structure:

```
|-- app
|   |-- models
|   |-- views
|   |-- controlers
|
|-- public
|   |-- coffeescript
|   |-- css
|   |-- js
|   |-- sass
|
|-- package.json
|-- Gruntfile.coffee
|-- Gemfile
```

*Please note I left out a few files and folders because this is just an example.*

I did a little Googling, and I did not find a good answer to my issue. What I am looking for is best practice. I would also like to note I added a few commands like `npm start` which starts a development web server for testing. This makes my life a lot easier. Has anyone else mixed Sinatra and GruntJS and is this acceptable?

For a full example check out [my github project.](https://github.com/Christianjuth/fwitter)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally used Sinatra or Grunt, so take my advice with a grain of salt. However, I have configured Rails to serve assets using Gulp.

From what I'm reading in the Sinatra documentation, Sinatra automatically serves up static files in the 'public' folder without any additional configuration.

I looked around and I didn't actually see an updated Grunt gem. The way I configured Rails and Gulp to work was to have Gulp run concurrently with Rails, and just have the Gulp build task run before I started up the server in production. That way, Rails could just pick up the compiled assets. I think a similar setup might work well for you.

Comment: This is what I am doing currently. The only difference is I am using Grunt through npm and not a gem. Essentially I am mixing Node and Ruby. Node is only being used to compile though and not actually in the actually website.